# How do we transfer a file to ALFRESCO through java

Tags: java, integration, alfresco

We have a PLM product which is now going to have some integration with CMS Alfresco. I have been asked to work with the integrations part. This is really challenging and interesting and am very much eager to start things off pretty early.

The plan is simple, to develop a UI that sends say , a FILE [ pdf/word ] to ALFRESCO. Now I understand that Alfresco is an open source system. But I dont think there is much of a tutorial kind of thing with Alfresco in the net. All I found out was documentation on Alfresco site and that is a bit intimidating.

I wanted to know how I can proceed understanding what API needs to be invoked for achieving something like this. So, please share your ideas.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Alfresco offers half a dozen different ways that'll work from Java, almost all of which are very well documented online! What have you tried so far? What is the rest of your stack looking like? What other integrations might you do later?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services). There are many tutorials and a [new book](http://www.manning.com/mueller/) out there on the web which will aid your learning, plus the [Apache Chemistry](https://chemistry.apache.org/) project provides client APIs for a range of different stacks (even if your stack does not have a client library available then uploading a file is as simple as making a HTTP POST/PUT call).

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve that.
If you are comfortable with JAVA and webservices there are various out of box webscript which you can consume directly.
You can also use Alfresco WebService API.
Check out SDK FirstWebservice Client.
You can modify it to accept you own file.
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SDK_4.0

Comment: I would strongly advise NOT to use the proprietary WebService (SOAP) API. CMIS offers similar capabilities with a choice between RESTful and SOAP bindings, and is much better supported.